# Best process for migrating WP to new host with limited access to original files?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on moving a WP site from a host that a web agent in Singapore made for a client, to my host.

The only files they were able to provide me for now is a compressed folder of what seems to be the public_html folder from the current host server. Looks like it has all the actual files, but not the original SQL database.

I am having two issues right now...

1) We do not yet have the domain. I set up a WP install on my host, and copied over the files that were provided to me. But now when I try going to wp-admin, it redirects me to the domain (which is on the pre-existing host of the web agent in Singapore). I looked in wp-config for WP_HOME or WP_SITEURL, and these values were not in the file. And since we do not have the SQL, I am not able to edit the database through SQL queries either.

2) It looks like the current config files are set to access a database on 
'us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (I am assuming this is the main host as well). Since I have the database host/user/password, is there any way I could use this access to download the SQL and transfer it to my server?

I don't use WP much, so any advice would be appreciated. Not sure if I could get this working with the limited access I have, or if I need to request a backup of the original SQL, or... ?

Comment: I'd say you need to request the original SQL. You may be able to connect to the RDS instance and access the mysql database with the credentials you have but this is unlikely because it would require port 3306 to be open in the instances security group. `mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p`. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Answer (score 0):

If their database server is set to accept connections only from a specific host(s) then you will not be able to connect.

But if you can, here is a detailed guide on how you can migrate the wordpress installation.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress